# How to create non-repeating Random String of size 5 using special characters (including space) only using java?

Tags: java, special-characters

I am trying to create String of size 5 using special characters only such as -

> ~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:\'\",<.>/?

which includes **space** also.

Below is the line of code which I tried :-

```
public static String randomSpecialCharacterString() {
    char[] possibleCharacters = (new String("~`!@ # $ %^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?")).toCharArray();
    String randomStr = RandomStringUtils.random( 5, 0, possibleCharacters.length-1, false, false, possibleCharacters, new SecureRandom());
    return randomStr;
}
```

But, it is not returning a non-repeating String. And also, the String with a space  should be returned.

For example - `@# ?/` and `!)( +`

I have gone through all the possible duplicates.

Comment: What's the deal with the space? Every random string should have one space somewhere?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - yes correct. And also, it should be non-repeating. So, right now, I am able to generate the string but sometimes, It doesn't return the string with spaces.

Comment: Your two examples: one is 6 characters including one space, and the other is 7 characters including one space. Question is a little bit unclear, because at the start you say you need a string of size 5...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - I am sorry about that. I have changed it. Please check.

Comment: Now one has 4 characters and the other 5.

Comment: first example has space at last.. so, when I am block quoting it.. it is removing the spaces at last

Comment: Now they're both 4 characters long. I give up.

Comment: You can just shuffle your `possibleCharacters` and take the first five.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `RESULT_STR_LENGTH` is 5:

1. If you don't want duplicates, simply randomize the order of `possibleCharacters`:

   ```
   char[] shuffledCharacters = new char[possibleCharacters.length];
   Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(possibleCharacters)).toArray(shuffledCharacters);
   ```
2. If a space must be in the result, then replace a random character with space (if you don't want duplicate spaces, make sure `possibleCharacters` doesn't contain any spaces):

   ```
   shuffledCharacters[new Random().nextInt(RESULT_STR_LENGTH)] = ' ';
   ```
3. Then return the first RESULT_STR_LENGTH characters as String:

   ```
   return new String(shuffledCharacters, 0, RESULT_STR_LENGTH);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 bugs: missing space character in characters list and count value (...length-1 means the last character from list will never be picked).

Non repeating Strings across invocations:

```
private static final char[] possibleCharacters = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?".toCharArray();
private static Set<String> used = new HashSet<>();
private static final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

public static String randomSpecialCharacterString() {
  String randomStr;
  do {
    randomStr = RandomStringUtils.random( 5, 0, possibleCharacters.length, false, false, possibleCharacters, rand);
  } while(used.contains(randomStr));
  used.add(randomStr);
  return randomStr;
}
```

Non repeating characters in String:

```
private static final char[] possibleCharacters = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?".toCharArray();
private static final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

public static String randomSpecialCharacterString() {
  final StringBuilder randomStr = new StringBuilder(5);

  IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> {
    String randomChar;
    do {
      randomChar = RandomStringUtils.random(1, 0, possibleCharacters.length, false, false, possibleCharacters, rand);
    } while (randomStr.indexOf(randomChar) >= 0);
    randomStr.append(randomChar);

  });
    int spacePosition = rand.nextInt(5);
    return randomStr.replace(spacePosition, spacePosition + 1, " ").toString();
}
```

Both combined:

```
private static final char[] possibleCharacters = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?".toCharArray();
private static Set<String> used = new HashSet<>();
private static final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

public static String randomSpecialCharacterString() {
  String randomStr;
  do {
    randomStr = randomSpecialCharacterNonRepeatedString();
  } while (used.contains(randomStr));
  used.add(randomStr);
  return randomStr;
}

  public static String randomSpecialCharacterNonRepeatedString() {
    final StringBuilder randomStr = new StringBuilder(5);

    IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> {
      String randomChar;
      do {
        randomChar = RandomStringUtils.random(1, 0, possibleCharacters.length, false, false, possibleCharacters,
            new SecureRandom());
      } while (randomStr.indexOf(randomChar) >= 0);
      randomStr.append(randomChar);

    });
    int spacePosition = rand.nextInt(5);
    return randomStr.replace(spacePosition, spacePosition + 1, " ").toString();
  }
```

Please note that this code is not thread safe.

Comment: Ach, should Strings across invocations don't repeat or characters in String should't repeat?

Comment: @Thilo Actually not. Then `used` will be initialied each time. To make it thread safe whole method needs to be synchronized.

Comment: I think the question is about non-repeating characters in the string. Not keeping track of the result strings not being generated a second time.

Comment: @zolv - Thanks zolv for the solution. The string should contain space character (at least 1 character should be space). I don't think this is replicate 
d here.

Comment: You are right. In Your question it's written "should be returned". It is a little bit misleading.